# HTML/PHP form is not sending any POST data

Tags: php, forms, post

when developing a registration page, i've come across a quite irrating issue.
When submitting the form via the submit button, I can see it sending like "user=myusername" over to the browser, but the PHP part isn't picking it up at all.
I've tried debugging via "echo" & "print_r" but they both showed empty, I am however getting errlor logs from zPanel.

Here's the PHP part of the code:

```
    if(isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['pw']) && isset($_GET['mail']))
{
    $username = $_POST["user"];
    $password = $_POST['pw'];
    $email = $_POST["mail"];
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($email)) header("Location: register.php?empty");
    else if(user_exists($username)) header("Location: register.php?exist");
    else if(email_exists($email)) header("Location: register.php?mailexist");
    else if($password != $repeat_pass) header("Location: register.php?wrongpw");
    else
    {
        register($username,$password,$ipaddress,$email);
        header("Location: register.php?registrationsuccess");
        exit();

    }
}
```

And here is the HTML part that triggers the above:

```
<form>
                <div>
                    <label for="username" class="control-label" style="color: #666; position: absolute; top: 110px;">Username</label>
                    <div class="input-group" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 8px; width: 300px;">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <label for="password" class="control-label" style="color: #666; position: absolute; top: 163px;">Password</label>
                    <div style="margin-left: 100px; width: 300px;" class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                      <input type="password" name="pw" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <label for="email" class="control-label" style="color: #666; position: absolute; top: 220px;">Email</label>
                    <div style="margin-left: 100px; width: 300px;" class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span></span>
                      <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" style="position: absolute; top: 265px; left: 125px;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 300px; font-size: 18px;">Register</button>
                </form>
```

And yes, this is with bootstrap.
Now, whenever you try to login, it actually does redirect you to the register.php?empty, stating that you have nothing entered in the fields.

And this is what zPanel spews at me:

```
[error] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username
```

[error] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password
[error] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email

Honestly, I have no idea whats causing all this trouble.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you didnt declear the method of the form. It should be `<form method="POST">`.

After that you need to change

```
if(isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['pw']) && isset($_GET['mail']))
```

TO

```
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pw']) && isset($_POST['mail']))
```

I think that will work. Let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. When I first set the PHP part up, the $_POST detail wasn't working at all (It just refreshed the page with all the 'user=user' name and etcetra. Now suddently it works, I suppose the 'form method' was the reason of it. This fixed it, I owe you one. Kind Regards.

Comment: Happy that could help you out. Regards. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the Code like this...

```
    if(isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['pw']) && isset($_GET['mail']))
{
    $username = $_GET["user"];
    $password = $_GET['pw'];
    $email = $_GET["mail"];
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($email)) header("Location: register.php?empty");
    else if(user_exists($username)) header("Location: register.php?exist");
    else if(email_exists($email)) header("Location: register.php?mailexist");
    else if($password != $repeat_pass) header("Location: register.php?wrongpw");
    else
    {
        register($username,$password,$ipaddress,$email);
        header("Location: register.php?registrationsuccess");
        exit();

    }
}
```

HTML should be something like this...

```
<form method="GET" action="action_page_name.php">
                <div>
                    <label for="username" class="control-label" style="color: #666; position: absolute; top: 110px;">Username</label>
                    <div class="input-group" style="margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 8px; width: 300px;">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <label for="password" class="control-label" style="color: #666; position: absolute; top: 163px;">Password</label>
                    <div style="margin-left: 100px; width: 300px;" class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                      <input type="password" name="pw" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <label for="email" class="control-label" style="color: #666; position: absolute; top: 220px;">Email</label>
                    <div style="margin-left: 100px; width: 300px;" class="input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span></span>
                      <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" style="position: absolute; top: 265px; left: 125px;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 300px; font-size: 18px;">Register</button>
                </form>
```

Before moving onto more development in PHP, you should get to know the difference between GET & POST.

[Visit a Website like this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)

Comment: There are more errors in your code. You are not passing value inside header() functions. You must assign a value to the variables that you are passing to register.php page.

Answer (score 0):

While submitting data in PHP-HTML, you have to use method property of '`<form>`. The method attribute specifies how to send form-data (the form-data is sent to the page specified in the action attribute).

The form-data can be sent as URL variables (with method="get") or as HTTP post transaction (with method="post").In `<form>` you have to mention the GET/POST method like

```
<form method="GET">
```

Also, if you are submitting the data to another page the `action` attribute should be set. Otherwise `action=""`.

```
 <form method="GET" action="actionpage.php">
```

Comment: since no method was supplied, the default would already be `GET`

Answer (score 0):

Your form is missing a method and an action. The action is the file that will receive and process the data. Method is how the form will send the data.

```
<form method="POST" action="file.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `name` for button `submit`:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

After that, check `isset` submit button:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
    //enter code here
}
```